# Connecting MySQL with connection pool in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database in NodeJS. It seems it is creating multiple pool connections from multiple sources, instead of using the old one.

If I try this in MySQL console:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

It shows many sleep connections.

Here is my connection file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

require('./env');
const config = require('.')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];
let pool;

function configDb(config) {
  const dbConfig = {
    host: config.host,
    user: config.username,
    password: config.password,
    database: config.database,
    connectionLimit : 100,
  };

  if (!pool) {
    pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
  }

  return pool;
}

function exec(query, values) {
  const db = configDb(config);

  return db.getConnection().then(conn => {
    console.log('QUERY: ', query, values);
    const res = conn.query(query, values);
    conn.release();
    return res;
  });
}

module.exports = {
  exec,
};
```

What could be a better approach to this?

Comment: Creating many idle connections is a known flaw of the mysql connection pool library, nothing bad in your code.